# Resizing Bootatrap4 Navigation bar not working acordingly

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

```css
 .navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-light{
        width:1920px;
        background-color:#eee;
        height:50px;
  }
  
  footer{
      background-color:grey;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:320px){
       .navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-light{
        width:100%;

     }     
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:985px){
    #tog{
        height:50px;
    }

}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"  id="tog" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a id="x" class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com">
                         <img style="padding-bottom:75px; "  id="image;" src="assets/logo.png" alt=" x">MANAGEMENT SYSTEM
                    </a>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"  type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" id="but"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-between" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <div class="col-2"></div>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/table">Details
                             </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/assigned-employees">Employees</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active ">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/bug-reporting">Report</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    
 
 
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
        <footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row footer-list-row">
                         <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6"  id="com">
                                    <h3>Company</h3>
                                    
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>About</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>News</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Careers</a>
                                        </li>
            
                                    </ul>
            
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-xs-6" id="sol">
                                    <h3>Solutions</h3>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Applications</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Planning</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Service</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Management</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
            
                            </div>
            
                        </div>
            
            
            
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6" id="part">
                                    <h3>Part</h3>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Partner</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Partner</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Login</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
            
                                </div>
                              
            
                                <div class="col-xs-6" id="contact">
                                    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Contact Us</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Addresses</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Feedback</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=''>Login</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
            
                                </div>
            
                            </div>
            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
</div>
</div>
```

I have implemented bootstrap 4 navigation bar inside my web application.Since it is little bit of tall than I expected  I needed to customize its height in to 50px. Soon after I did the customization, mobile view stated to show a malicious behavior. when I try to expand the menu by clicking the "List Icon" it expands the list underneath of other DIV s like follow (Like when it has z index -1)

[List View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDNXh.png)

This is the html code I used for navigation bar

```
  <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"  id="tog" role="navigation" style="width:1920px; height:50px;">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a id="x" class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com">
                     <img style="padding-bottom:75px; "  id="image;" src="assets/logo.png" alt="Dispute Bills">ATTENDENCE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM
                </a>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"  type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" id="but"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-between" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <div class="col-2"></div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/table">My Details
                         </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/assigned-employees">Assigned Employees List</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active ">
                        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/bug-reporting">Report Bugs</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>
```

I have tried by changing the z-index. But it didn't work for me. any clue on this please

Comment: Post the html code here instead of a screenshot so that it is easy for people who wish to help you...

Comment: done sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @E.L.N.D.Madubhashini brother why you have given inline width and height...??? you should be giving height in media query and you should be using width as 100% but in css not in html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 Mobile Navbar Disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914245/bootstrap-4-mobile-navbar-disappearing)

Comment: In my code I have given width and height in media query that code is little bit long, that's why I didn't attach it  here. I have given inline width and height here because of easiness.

Comment: The above given answer  is not a solution to my question because here navigation bar height should be fixed(50px) value for all views.